# Rails Single Results from Multiple Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, union, rails-activerecord

Using Rails 4.2

I have two models, `suppliers` and `clients`. Both models contain a `name` (string) and `email` (string). They do not have any relationship between them.

I would like to generate a list of all the names and emails from both suppliers and clients. In this list I would also like to know if the partner is a supplier or client.

**Controller**

```
@suppliers = Supplier.all
@clients = Client.all

@all_partners = (@suppliers + @clients).sort { |x, y| x.name <=> y.name }
```

**View**

```
<% @all_partners.each do |partner| %>
  <%= partner.name %>, <%= partner.email %>, <%= partner.type %>
  <!-- I need some way to know if the partner type is a supplier or client -->
<% end %>
```

How can I put in which type of partner it is? Is there a way to do this with one single AR call or query? This is basically how to use an SQL Union statement in Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the class name of the object I believe `<%= partner.class.model_name.human %>`

Comment: That did help. Thanks. I also have a field in `clients` that doesn't exist in `suppliers` that I output in the view using `try`

Comment: Can't reduce the number of queries though without changes to the tables. So I guess I can only answer part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help all.

I ended up using the same controller as in the question, with some additional information in the view.

**View**

```
<% @all_partners.each do |partner| %>
  <%= partner.name %>, <%= partner.email %>, <%= partner.try(:client_type) %>, <%= partner.class.model_name.human  %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Union in ActiveRecord works only within a single model. You could use union for two different tables using raw SQL, something like this:

```
Supplier.connection.execute("(SELECT id, ..., 'suppliers' as table FROM suppliers WHERE...) UNION (SELECT id,... 'clients' as table FROM clientsWHERE...)")
```

but the result would be of type PG::Result.
So the best way, unfortunately, is to use two ActiveRecord queries.
OR if clients and suppliers have similar fields, you could put them in one table

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(is_supplier: true)
  scope :clients, -> { where(is_supplier: false) }
end
```

so `Partner.all` will output only suppliers, `Partner.unscoped` - all partners

Comment: Putting them in one table is probably the best solution. Although since the app does so much work on suppliers it would make the rest of the code a bit cumbersome if I continually need to ignore the clients.

Comment: you could just add a field indicating the type of objects and create a default_scope to select suppliers, and another scope to select users, so it will require only minor changes to the code

Comment: added example to answer